# Xcode app layout not working on all devices

Tags: ios, xcode, layout

I'm developing an app with xcode/swift and the constraints that i put are only working for one screen size.

I looked for solutions, i saw things involving auto-layout but nothing has worked for me.

[What i Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNAeY.png)

[What i have when i change the screen format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi2jf.jpg)

Can someone please help me, what is the best solution to have the layout adapt itself to the different screen resolutions ?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review ]ask]. Your first step should be to search for `iOS auto-layout tutorial` and go through several tutorials on how to use auto-layout and constraints and try to apply what you learn to your current layout. Then, if you are having trouble, come back and post specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution in your case is to use `UICollectionView`, create one `UICollectionViewCell` with label and change background according to your data. Then, set your `UIViewController` as `delegateFlowLayout`, which has method:

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
               sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Here you can calculate size for your according to screen size. `UIScreen.main.bounds.size` returns `CGSize` which is size of the screen.

---

Delegate methods can be used to set inter item and line spacing between cells.

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

---

[Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH3-SW1) from Apple about collection view.

Comment: thanks, i'll look into that. But isn't the auto layout from xcode supposed to do that for me ?

Comment: @Ozymandias it does, but creating 4 identical buttons is bad idea.